# getIssuerX500Principal().getName() returns wired name

Tags: java, cryptography, x509certificate

1) I'm retrieving the issuer of a X509Certificate as follows.

```
String issuerDn(final X509Certificate cert) {
    return cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName();
}
```

cert.toString() shows the issuer as:

```
EMAILADDRESS=root@someperson, CN=someCommonName, OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit, O=SomeOrganization, L=SomeCity, ST=SomeState, C=--
```

However cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName() returns the following:

```
1.2.<SOME DIGITS>=#<SOME DIGITS>,CN=someCommonName,OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=--
```

However if I used cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName("RFC1779"), it will return the issuer correctly (i.e. with root@someperson ).

Can anyone please explain whether it is correct to use cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName("RFC1779") for retrieving issuer from X509Certifcate since RFC 2253 obsoletes RFC 1779.

2) I noticed that if the Organization is something like "{SOME DIGITS}" (i.e. open brace and some digits), getIssuerX500Principal().getName() returns something like the following.

```
O=|0|{|0|7|0|E|0|F|0|2|0|B|0|1| ....
```

And still getIssuerX500Principal().getName("RFC1779") returns it correctly. Can anyone explain why is that and whats the workaround?

3) In case issuer name contains null bytes in between, what is the expected behavior of getIssuerX500Principal().getName() ?

Comment: Your question is flying under the radar Fahim, I just see it because I clicked on your profile. I'll add some much used tags, you should too.

Comment: What are the digits in `"1.2.<SOME DIGITS>"` concretely? Have you tried searching for it on http://www.oid-info.com/?